# How to merge tables returned by function called in select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a function that takes a `nvarchar` and returns a table of one column and variable amount of rows.

The problem is I need to call the funcion like this

```
SELECT fn_My_Func(V.Value)
FROM tblValues V
```

How can I call the function for each row in the table and then merge the results in a single resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use cross apply

```
SELECT *  FROM tblValues V
CROSS APPLY fn_My_Func(V.Value) L;
```

The APPLY operator allows you to join two table expressions; the right table expression is processed every time for each row from the left table expression. As you might have guessed, the left table expression is evaluated first and then the right table expression is evaluated against each row of the left table expression for the final result set. The final result set contains all the selected columns from the left table expression followed by all the columns of the right table expression.

### SQL Server APPLY operator has two variants; CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY

- The CROSS APPLY operator returns only those rows from the left table
  expression (in its final output) if it matches with the right table
  expression. In other words, the right table expression returns rows
  for the left table expression match only.
- The OUTER APPLY operator returns all the rows from the left table
  expression irrespective of its match with the right table expression.
  For those rows for which there are no corresponding matches in the
  right table expression, it contains NULL values in columns of the
  right table expression.
- So you might conclude, the CROSS APPLY is equivalent to an INNER JOIN
  (or to be more precise its like a CROSS JOIN with a correlated
  sub-query) with an implicit join condition of 1=1 whereas the OUTER
  APPLY is equivalent to a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not working for me. I'm getting the error "'fn_My_Func' is not a recognized function name"

Comment: @DSantiagoBC Your edit only makes this response and the comments incomprehensible. You corrected the syntax errror in the response - why? Gordon posted a working query and you should have, by now, marked an answer. You shouldn't just randomly change what others write - regardless of how correct it might be. And how about marking answers - because that is how SO is designed to work.

Comment: @SMor I thought it was better to change this answer and accept it because the explanation is quite complete, and it is more useful for anyone who have the same question. Also I have already clarified it does works with the correction I made, so I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross apply`, but the simplest syntax is:

```
SELECT mf.*
FROM tblValues V CROSS APPLY
     dbo.fn_My_Func(V.Value) mf;
```

When calling the function, you need to include the schema name.